# Set Android Wear notification background image in GCM notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, wear-os

When sending a Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) notification to Android smartphone it gets automatically forwarded to Android Wear - the message and the icon pops up. I was wondering if there is a way to set a background image of the notification in GCM request JSON, without actually changing the code of the app?

Answer (score 0):

use google sync data api, your can do this
setLocalOnly in Handheld apk
send the notification data to wear apk
notify the notification in wear apk